# Cannot Write to www and update wordpress at same time

Tags: samba, chmod, wordpress, chown

I have LAMP installed on my Ubuntu 14.04 server and am using apache as a web server.  I am going to be using the web server for Wordpress primarily.  The problem I am running into is that I cannot update Wordpress or add plugins the standard way.  It keeps asking me for my FTP credentials.

I did some Googling and was able to fix the Wordpress update problem by changing ownership of the www folder to www-data:www-data.  The problem with doing this, though, is I no longer am able to edit the shared files through Samba. When I change ownership to user:www-data I can modify the files but cannot update Wordpress without it asking for FTP. The folder is chmod 755 and I DO NOT want to go to 777.

So... can anyone help point me in the right direction to correct this? I am brand new to Ubuntu and would really appreciate any pointers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add your samba user to www-data group and change permissions to 775
useradd -G www-data your_samba_user

Comment: Awesome, that was it. I already had my user added to www-data but I just needed to change the permissions.  Thank you for the quick reply!